# Solving for the value of $a,b$ in $f(x)=(ax+b)(x^5+1)-(5x+1)$ s.t. $(x^2+1)|f(x)$

Tags: functions, polynomials

> $Q.$ If  $f(x)=(ax+b)(x^5+1)-5x-1$ is divisible by $x^2+1$ . Then the value of $2a+3b$ $?$

**MY APPROACH :** We have , $(x^2+1)|f(x)$ then $(x-i)|f(x)$ and $(x+i)|f(x)$ .

So by [Factor Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_theorem) we have $f(-i)=0$ and $f(i)=0$ $$f(i)=-a+bi+(a-5)i+b-1=0$$ $$f(-i)=-a-bi-(a-5)i+b-1=0$$

By this I concluded that $a-b=-1$ . But this is not enough information to solve the problem .

Comment: So far you got $a=b-1$, then substitute that back into one of the equations and solve.

Comment: So basically you can Conclude from @lone student 's solution that $(a+b-5)x+(b-a-1)=0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have

$$\begin{align}&ax^6+bx^5+x(a-5)+(b-1)=P(x)(x^2+1)+mx+n \\\\
\implies &\begin{cases} mi+n=-a+bi+i(a-5)+(b-1)\\-mi+n=-a-bi-i(a-5)+(b-1)\end{cases}\\\\
\implies &\begin{cases} n=\frac{2(b-1)-2a}{2}=b-a-1\\m=\frac{2bi+2i(a-5)}{2i}=a+b-5\\
\end{cases}\\\\
\implies&\begin{cases}n=0,\thinspace b-a=1\\m=0,\thinspace a+b=5
\end{cases} \\\\
\implies &~~a=2, \thinspace b=3\\\\ \implies &~~2a+3b=13. \end{align}$$

Comment: You seem to have overlooked the condition $x^2+1\mid f(x)$, which gives the simultaneous constraints $a+b=5$ and $b=a+1$ which _has_ a unique solution.

Comment: @PrasunBiswas ʘ‿ʘ Exactly $\ddot\smile$

Answer (score 2):

You have 90% of the solution as you states $a-b=-1$ similarly equating imaginary parts to $0$ you should have $a+b=5$ which give $a=2,b=3$.